# Do evade skill and evade accessory stack?

Tags: persona-4

I was wondering about stackable effects and came accross a good [FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/945498-shin-megami-tensei-persona-4/faqs/54981) <sup>[*further down is the relevant part of it*]</sup>

However, there is one thing not mentioned in it, which I was wondering about and is also the reason I googled for it in the first place:

What if Kanji knows *Evade Wind* (`Triples evasion rate against Wind attacks`) while carrying *Eye of Wind* (`Greatly raises Evasion Rate to Wind attacks`) at the same time?
It looks like this would fall into rule nr. 3 (`a passive skill and an accessory providing the same effect NEVER stack`), but the accessory doesn't say it *triples* the evasion rate, only that it *greatly increases* it.

Because of that, I am uncertain if I should give Kanji the *Eye of wind*, or if I should give him something more useful instead. Of course, I also intend to do the same for other party members with other elemental weaknesses.

So, do evasion skills and accessories stack or not?

---

Here is the relevant part of the FAQ:

> 1. Elemental (Fire/Ice/Elec/Wind) effects DO stack. However, the stacking is
>      limited to a total of TWO skills or accessories, and skills take precedence
>      over accessories.
>      Examples:
>      (+) Fire Boost and Fire Amp
>      (+) Fire Boost and Fire Vow
>      (+) Fire Amp and Kagutsuchi Vow (Amp and +50% accessory is the largest
>         effect you can have)
>      (+/-) Fire Boost, Fire Amp, and Kagutsuchi Vow results in only Fire Boost
>         and Fire Amp stacking
> 2. Resist effects from affinities, skills, equipment, and spells stack:
>      (+) Ukobach (innate Resist Fire) + Resist Fire (learned at Level 6) +
>         Kagutsuchi Pin (Fire damage down 50%) + Red Wall all stack
> 3. Barring Rules 1 and 2, a passive skill and an accessory providing the same
>      effect NEVER stack.
>      Examples:
>      (-) Apt Pupil and Omega Drive (quadruples critical hit chance? I wish)
>      (-) Angelic Grace and Cat Whisker
>      (-) Endure and Partial Award
> 4. Barring Rule 3, HP and SP regenerative effects DO stack and take effect in
>      succession.
>      Examples:
>      (+) Regenerate 1, Regenerate 2, Regenerate 3
>      (+) Regenerate 1, Regenerate 2, Space Badge
>      (+) Invigorate 1, Invigorate 2, Invigorate 3
>      (+) Mage's Mark, Invigorate 2, Invigorate 3
> 5. All other multi-tiered effects do NOT stack. The highest-tiered effect takes
>      precedence.
>      Examples:
>      (-) Growth 1, Growth 2, Growth 3 (only Growth 3 takes effect)
>      (-) Counter, Counterstrike, High Counter (only High Counter takes effect)
> 6. Ailment Boost and the Boost skills of individual ailments do NOT stack.
>      Ailment Boost takes precedence.
> 7. Other combinations that either do or do not stack:
>      (+) EXP-boosting weapon and EXP-boosting armor (i.e. Musashi Shinai and
>         Haikara Shirt/Mandara Robe)
>      (+) Cool Breeze and Relaxing Wave
>      (+) Apt Pupil/Omega Drive and Revolution (thanks Nasada19)
>      (-) Evasion skills/equipment granting evasion skills and an affinity that
>         is better than Resist (i.e. Null/Repel/Absorb). In other words, for
>         example, if you have Null/Repel/Absorb Physical, you will never dodge
>         physical attacks (meaning enemies will never miss and fall down). This
>         is because the game assumes a general mechanic that prefers the
>         automatic nullification of the attack. This may be something to think
>         about if you really like letting enemies miss and fall down; in that
>         case, something like Tam Lin's innate Resist Physical combined with the
>         Evade Physical he learns might be more up your alley.